# Why are Low Level Mouse Hooks Causing Lag

Tags: c++, mouse-hook

I'm trying to make an application that just detects if the left mouse button is held down. In trying to do this, as well as learn mouse hooks, I copy-pasted a hook from an example source (https://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/119909-setwindowshookex-lowlevelmouseproc.html) just to see what it would do. The problem is that it lags my computer. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

HHOOK g_Hook;
HANDLE g_evExit;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc (int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        const char *msg;
        char msg_buff[128];
        switch (wParam)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: msg = "WM_LBUTTONDOWN"; break;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP: msg = "WM_LBUTTONUP"; break;
            case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: msg = "WM_RBUTTONDOWN"; break;
            case WM_RBUTTONUP: msg = "WM_RBUTTONUP"; break;
            default: 
                sprintf(msg_buff, "Unknown msg: %u", wParam); 
                msg = msg_buff;
                break;
        }//switch

        const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *p = 
            reinterpret_cast<const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        cout << msg << " - [" << p->pt.x << ',' << p->pt.y << ']' << endl;

        static bool left_down = false;
        static bool right_down = false;
        switch (wParam)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: left_down = true; break;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:   left_down = false; break;
            case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: right_down = true; break;
            case WM_RBUTTONUP:   right_down = false; break;
        }//switch

        if (left_down && right_down)
            SetEvent(g_evExit);
    }//if

    return CallNextHookEx(g_Hook, code, wParam, lParam); 
}//LowLevelMouseProc


int main()
{
    g_evExit = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
    if (!g_evExit)
    {
        cerr << "CreateEvent failed, le = " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }//if

    g_Hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, &LowLevelMouseProc, 
                              GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
    if (!g_Hook)
    {
        cerr << "SetWindowsHookEx() failed, le = " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }//if

    cout << "Press both left and right mouse buttons to exit..." << endl;

    MSG msg;
    DWORD status;
    while (1)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

        status = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &g_evExit, FALSE, 
                                           INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
        if (status == (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1))
        {
            // there are messages to process, eat em up
            continue;
        }//if
        else
        {
            // assume g_evExit is signaled
            break;
        }//else
    }//while

    cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_Hook);
    CloseHandle(g_evExit);
    return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to try to resolve your problem?

Comment: I think it's a problem with how I'm removing the hook. I've tried playing with the remove mechanism a little bit, but nothing major. It didn't help, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [message pump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940736/4759433). The code you posted uses [`PeekMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea) in combination with [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects), but it's probably a better idea to use [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) along with [`TranslateMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translatemessage) and [`DispatchMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage), as showcased in [How to manually run message pump in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341175/4759433):

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 1) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

With this loop, I was able to set up a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook with [`SetWindowsHookExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa)  without having the mouse input lag, and correctly receiving all events.

Make sure the hook is installed on the same thread that will pump the messages.